# Benefits for option dealer delta-hedging an inter-dealer OTC equity option

Tags: hedging

What benefit(s) is (are) attained by **options dealers** in bilaterally exchanging the cash for shares to delta-hedge an inter-dealer OTC equity option they are trading?

Comment: You may find https://quant.stackexchange.com more suitable for this question.

Comment: I am wondering if this is a homework -type problem ?

Comment: @fattie, I'm waiting for the guy's teacher to show up with the answer...